# Prove that: $\lim \limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-T_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n}} =0 $

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a function that is differentiable $n$ times at the point $x_0$.

Prove that:  $$\lim \limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-T_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n}} =0. $$

It's said that it's Taylor's first Theorem. But couldn't find an understandable proof for that. Can some help simplifying the concept?

Note: $T_n(x)$ is the polynomial to the power $n$ .

Comment: I think it'd be wise to tell the audience what is $\;T_n\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc is it clear now?

Comment: There should be more information. At least about $f(x)$.

Comment: Take a look at [Taylors formula with an error term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) and use that $f^{(n+1)}(x_0)$ is finite.

Comment: @Winther but Its not said that $f$ is differentiable $k+1$ times. .

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. What about using L'Hopitals rule $n$ times? For example $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - T_2(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x) -f'(0) - xf''(0)}{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f''(x) - f''(0)}{2} = 0$

Comment: @Winther yes but I don't have a given polynomial to derive. its like a general fact, but I'd like to see ur idea if u write it.

Comment: You do have a polynomial: $T_n(x) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^i}{i!}$ and $f^{(k)}(x_0) - T_n^{(k)}(x_0) = 0$ for all $k<n$ so you can use L'Hopitals.

Comment: @Winther He can *not* use l'Hospital since for the last term in $\;T_n\;$ he'd need the $\;n+1$-th derivative of $\;f\;$ . Instead, he can use l'H for the $\;n-1\;$ first terms of that polynomial, and for thelast one it follows at once fromthe general theorem

Comment: @Timbuc That is a strange comment. First you say that he can not use L'Hopital then you say he can. Anyway, you are of course absolutely correct about my typo above, use L'Hopital $n-1$ times and the continuity of $f^{(n)}(x)$ at $x=x_0$ gives the result as in my example above.

Comment: @Winther What is unclear to you? I wrote he can't use l'H in the *whole* expression but only for the first $\;n-1\;$ terms as he can't differentiate the $\;n$- th derivative and then for the last temr of $\;T_n\;$, i.e. the residue, etc. What's strange in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use L'Hosital's Rule $(n-1)$-times. First we look at how to differentiate $T_n$ $(n-1)$-times. Since $T_n$ is given by
\begin{align*}
T_n(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k \\ &=f(x_0)+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{(n-1)!}(x-x_0)^{n-1}+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^{n},
\end{align*} differentiation with respect to $x$ $(n-1)$-times will kill all terms up to order $n-2$. The remaining part is then
\begin{align*}
T_n^{(n-1)}(x)=f^{(n-1)}(x_0)+f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0).
\end{align*}
Using this we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-T_n(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}&=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)-f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)}{n!(x-x_0)} \\ &=\frac{1}{n!}\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f^{(n)}(x_0)\right) \\ &=
\frac{1}{n!}\left(f^{(n)}(x_0)-f^{(n)}(x_0)\right)\\ &=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: I didn't get what did u substitute the $T_n(x)$ with. could u elaborate?

Comment: Ok I'm sorry if this was to quick. I'll add some detail.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani, $(d/dx)^{n-1}$ kills every $(x-x_0)^k$ with $k<n-1$